# Set font size and color in title of shinydashboard box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I change the font size and color of `title` in `shinydashboard box()`?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12)),
    fluidRow(
      box(title="Title")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
r
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a header tag and `style` option within it.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12)),
    fluidRow(
      box(title=h3("Title", style = 'font-size:42px;color:blue;'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]